# How to enable startup sound on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: sound, startup, 20.04

I was wondering if there is a way to enable the Ubuntu Startup Sound as it is not enabled by default. My Ubuntu OS is 20.04.

Comment: when loginbscreen shows that time or when desktop??

Comment: I have an autostart set to run `paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg` (it uses `paplay` or pulse-audio-play to play the default sound I used to hear long ago.. or if it's not what I heard back ~11.04, it's one of the installed sounds available).  Sorry I'm not using GNOME so I can't direct assuming you're using a desktop and not server, adjust for your 20.04 system.

Comment: It's fine. But I eventually found out that they changed the folder directory of the sounds. I'm still new to the 20.04 LTS system :). It's actually paplay /usr/share/sounds/yaru/stero/system-ready.oga

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You wanted a different sound to what I was thinking (ie. the old sound from 10.10 & before) but the directory you gave doesn't exist on my system, but `system-read.oga` exists in the folder (ubuntu not yaru) from my comment (a difference likely because our systems are installed from different releases...  Feel free to write up your own answer though, in time you can accept it for rep.

Comment: No. In the newer version (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), they had changed the sound directory to yaru. But I was just wondering how to enable the startup sound in my computer.

Comment: are you looking for sound when the system is ready to login or once you login??

Comment: You can add this command at startup: `canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"`. You can change the ID to `system-ready` too. This works even if you're using an custom sound theme

Answer (score 8):

Unless you want to mess with cron, systemd, and/or similar utilities, this just isn't possible with giving you the startup sound on the login screen [at least easily in my opinion]. That method will require extensive use of the terminal.

Note, the `pa-play` method calls upon PulseAudio, which has been replaced (but still usable with the newer PipeWire) in Ubuntu distributions some time after 2022, if my memory serves me correctly. (Mods/Community feedback is welcomed to correct this!)

I suggest using the `canberra-gtk-play` method. That has worked consistently for me, regardless of complete Ubuntu 20.04+ installations or persistent USBs. Unfortunately, the result of this method doesn't give you a boot sound when you reach the login screen - it gives you the login sound much like when you sign on to your user account in Windows XP.

Launch "Startup Applications", and click "Add". Here's what you need to put in Startup Applications' dialog box:

Name: GNOME Login Sound (or whatever you want to name it)

Command: `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"`
Description: Plays a sound at login (or whatever you choose)

Typically you'd use `desktop-login` or `system-ready` as the boot sound, unless you specify otherwise via GNOME Tweaks or other methods. You can also replace the file with another ogg file of your choosing by replacing `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg` to make it easy

**The command field is very sensitive. Please don't add unnecessary spacing.** It won't work otherwise...

Anyways, that should help you activate the startup sound on Ubuntu 20.04 on login with consistency. Save your work and reboot to see (or rather hear) your hard work pay off once you login.

Comment: I interpreted the question as **before** login sound. Your answer appears to be **after** login sound.

Comment: That is the case - for some reason, I can't get the boot script to trigger the sound - and it doesn't appear to want to have audio on at login.

Comment: Probably because at login screen the user ID running the show is `gdm` and not your own until after you log in.

Comment: Bingo, that's the problem @WinEnuuchs2Unix

Comment: This only plays the old sound when the file has been specified or in GNOME Tweaks you set "Ubuntu" sounds instead of Yaru

Comment: As of 2023, in Zorin OS which is based on Ubuntu 20.04, this feature is there by default and we just have to enable it.

Comment: As far as I can recall, only the PulseAudio daemon got practically superseded by PipeWire; the rest of PulseAudio aren't and can still be used with PipeWire. Also PulseAudio isn't removed from the repos.