# How to enable Startup Sound in Ubuntu 21.10? Enabling a Startup Program method ain't working

Tags: sound, startup, 21.10, startup-applications

I searched for it and found an easy way to enable startup sound via the Startup Application app. I added the program as instructed and restarted to hear the sound. Unfortunately, there was no sound produced. This couldn't be a problem with the speakers as it works very well in playing the system and apps notification.

Below is the program I added:

[image: Edit Startup Program]

Comment: Oh, instead of 21.10, I committed a typo of 21.14. @guiverc

Comment: Correcting your question then would have been the better fix.  Comments are for us to ask questions for you, you add the additional (*or in this case corrected*) details to your question (*we then remove comments as a cleaner question encourages more readers/answers*)

Comment: We can't read your text in the *screen grab* (*snippet*) you provided... My own works with `paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg` as the command - but your full command cannot be read...  Does the file you have as operand exist??  My own example exists as found in the `ubuntu-sounds` package which I have installed.

Comment: (paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg)

This is the command I typed in to enable startup sound with reference to - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232364/how-to-enable-startup-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04 @guiverc

Comment: Apologies, but as I'm new here, I didn't know from where to edit the question and correct it to 21.10 from 21.14...